# Django forms, getting a select box from a different model

Tags: python, django, forms

Hay, say i have 2 models listing and category.

How would i use djangos form framework to automatically create a select drop down box for category?

```
class NewListingForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
    category  ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), 
                                  empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

Comment: Displays them as 'Category Object'. How do i display the name of them?

Comment: from the docs, "The \_\_unicode\_\_ method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field's choices;"

Comment: yep as sjh said, you need to define __unicode__ on the model. Or you could subclass label_from_instance as mentioned in the docs.